# print data inside key records in python

Tags: python

So i m new to python , i have a list of records with different keys in it, and some of keys have further records in that, it is basically a json structure , i want to iterate one of keys and get individual fields from it , so  my data is like

```
{
"ts" : Timestamp(1445849525, 15),
"h" : NumberLong("-4015330114951674248"),
"v" : 2,
"op" : "u",
"ns" : "myapp.emp",
"o2" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c04ffe4b0babdea123e49")
},
"o" : {
    "$set" : {
        "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2015-10-26T08:52:05.492Z"),
        "version" : NumberLong(8069)
    }
}
}
{
"ts" : Timestamp(1445849525, 16),
"h" : NumberLong("-581855468697041160"),
"v" : 2,
"op" : "u",
"ns" : "myapp.address",
"o2" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("555a00bfe4b00cf66524a39a")
},
"o" : {
    "$set" : {
        "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2015-10-26T08:52:05.495Z"),
        "version" : NumberLong(25495),
        "reason" : "logging check",
    }
}
}
```

and my code is

```
results = db.find()
for record in results:
    for rec in  record['o']:
        print(rec)
```

it gives the output as

```
$set
```

now i want to print all keys inside $set object except version field , how can i do this ? help

Comment: print record['o'][rec].keys() will not work ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: giving me above error

Comment: and if you print the record variable, it prints the same data you posted in the question ?

Comment: yes, and when i print record['o'], it gives me {'$set': {'orderCanceledBy': ObjectId('556c1f4ce4b0b31213f2cd35'), 'version': 4, 'lastUpdated': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 8, 52, 6, 410000), 'reason': 'oplog - query logging check'}}

Answer (score 0):

This code returning all keys from property $set without "version"

```
results = db.find()
for record in results:
    if results[record].get('$set'):
        properties = [prop for prop in results[record]['$set'] if prop != 'version']
```

Comment: it is returning this, ['$', 's', 'e', 't'] , spillting the $set key

Comment: getting error "" pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query ""
 at this line  "" if results[record].get('$set'): " "

Comment: What type of a variable result ? In your example is the dictionary